# Android Theme style file merge

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-resources, android-styles

Describe my situation in short, I have a multi themes project with `style.xml` and `style.xml(v21)`. The only difference of these two versions is that in each theme of v21 version has these two line in addition:
`<item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>`

And I don't what two maintain two style files since they are too familiar, so is there any way I can merge these two style xml file ,or make the v21 one extends `style.xml` and when I what to make some modification, I only have to work with `style.xml`

Comment: what is your `minSdkVersion` ?

Comment: minSdkversion = 17 @aksacha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

Place this in your "Normal" theme folder

```
<!--Standard-->
<style name="CommonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!--Place all common elements here-->
</style>

<!--Standard-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="CommonTheme">

</style>
```

Place this in your V21 folder

```
<!--V21-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="CommonTheme">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: A nice solution, though `CommonTheme` in addtion, but these seems to be diffficult to simplify further,